# Xamarin.forms button align

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to make the button nice however there seems to be a gap between the two buttons. Is there any way to make the gap closer so it's nicer? I've attached a screenshot for reference

[image]

These are my current code for my design.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

 <Button Text="View Event" BackgroundColor="#d3d3d3" TextColor="Black" />
<Button  Grid.Column="1" Text="Cancel" BackgroundColor="#d3d3d3" TextColor="Black"/>
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Grid.ColumnSpacing` has a value of 6 by default so try setting that to 0:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1"
      ColumnSpacing="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

 <Button Text="View Event" BackgroundColor="#d3d3d3" TextColor="Black" />
<Button  Grid.Column="1" Text="Cancel" BackgroundColor="#d3d3d3" TextColor="Black"/>
</Grid>
```

You might also want to set `Button.BorderRadius` to 0 and add a border around the buttons.

Comment: @JoshSoh Sweet. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here in Grid.ColumnSpacing has a value of 6 by default so try setting that to 0:..So this will solve your problem